# Rails noob: rails_admin giving me "undefined local variable or method "current _user" on Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, rails-admin

I've followed this:

https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

And I think I've done everything needed, bundle install, rake db:migrate etc but I can't get rid of:

ActionView::Template::Error (undefined local variable or method `current_user' for #):

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

`current_user` is a method provided by Devise - are you using Devise in the app you're trying to admin?

Comment: Hi, thanks for you reply.

This page : https://github.com/sferik/rails_admin

says that Devise is installed by rails_admin. Do I need to add the devise gem explicitly?

Comment: I just added Devise gem and now get this:

NoMethodError (undefined method `root_path' for #<Devise::FailureApp:0x000000056420d0>):

Comment: did you follow the device instructions for adding a root path to your routes.rb?